# How to check if there is a integer in dataframe and add words before it

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, integer

My Dataframe [image]

My code-

```
for x in df.ROAD_NAME_NUMBER:
    if int(x) == x:
        df.ROAD_NAME_NUMBER= 'Road '+ df.ROAD_NAME_NUMBER
```

I getting the error- `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Avenue 5, Lane 23'`

My expected dataframe should look like this -
[image]

When any integer will be found in dataframe add "Road" before it.Otherwise ignore.

---

```
import pandas a pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ROAD_NAME_NUMBER':['4','2','1','8','2','AVE 5,LANE 2']})

>>> print(df)
  ROAD_NAME_NUMBER
0                4
1                2
2                1
3                8
4                2
5     AVE 5,LANE 2
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. 
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)...[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ... 
[You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755) ...

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `ROAD_NAME_NUMBER` column be text, you could try using `str.replace` here:

```
df["ROAD_NAME_NUMBER"] = df["ROAD_NAME_NUMBER"].str.replace(r'^(\d+)$', r'Road \1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using something like this:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: 'Road ' + x['ROAD_NAME_NUMBER'] if type(x['ROAD_NAME_NUMBER']) == int else x['ROAD_NAME_NUMBER'])
```

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable not to iterate over DataFrame columns as you've tried. This should work in your case:

```
df.loc[df.ROAD_NAME_NUMBER.astype(str).str.isdigit(), 'ROAD_NAME_NUMBER'] = "Road " + df.ROAD_NAME_NUMBER.astype(str)
```